# Как сделать окно подписи на канал в telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, api, бот, telegram

Как сделать окно подписи на канал в telegram без перехода в этот канал .
Видел такое в боте, скрин:

[image]

При нажатии на кнопку выпадает такое окно, подскажите хоть в какую сторону API bot telegram смотреть, гугл не помог(